# LCRNG sequence prediction

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

I have an LCRNG sequence defined as followed:
$$x_{n+1}=x_n\cdot1103515245+24691\mod{2^{32}}$$
We start with a random 32-bit integer $x_0$, and we will extract from the sequence two integers A and B between 0 and 24. We get A by doing:
$$A = \left\lfloor\frac{x_1}{171835392}\right\rfloor$$
And we get B by doing:
$$B = \left\lfloor\frac{x_n}{2^{16}}\right\rfloor+2^{16}\cdot\left\lfloor\frac{x_{n+1}}{2^{16}}\right\rfloor\mod25$$
*Note: this is akin to concatenating the high 16 bits of two advances in the LCRNG.*
As soon as B equals A, we stop advancing the LCRNG. The goal is to "search" for B. Bruteforcing this problem is trivial, but I'm looking for a mathematical solution that wouldn't require a loop in terms of programming. I think I'm trying to solve this for the **smallest** $n$, basically:
$$\left\lfloor\frac{x_1}{171835392}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{x_n}{2^{16}}\right\rfloor+2^{16}\cdot\left\lfloor\frac{x_{n+1}}{2^{16}}\right\rfloor\mod25$$
Reformulated in terms of only $x_0$ and $x_n$, we get this:
$$\left\lfloor\frac{x_0\cdot1103515245+24691\mod{2^{32}}}{171835392}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{x_n}{2^{16}}\right\rfloor+2^{16}\cdot\left\lfloor\frac{x_n\cdot1103515245+24691\mod{2^{32}}}{2^{16}}\right\rfloor\mod25$$
I am familiar with modular arithmetic as a concept, but wouldn't even know where to start to solve an equation such as this one. Any help would be appreciated.